# VSTO document-level customization Intercept Commands

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

We are currently bulding a set of corporate templates using C# VSTO document-level customizations. We need to intercept the Paste command and change the content before it is pasted into the document. For example if a users is pasting an image we would also insert a caption with it, or if a user pastes a table it would be formatted appropriately. How do we intercept this event? Can it be done in a general way so that we can also see other commands?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [Catching Paste Operations](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use repurpose commands. Here is the [how to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

In Ribbon.xml

```
<commands>
    <command idMso="Paste" onAction="CustomPaste"/>
  </commands>
```

In Ribbon.cs

```
public void CustomPaste(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
        {
            //Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Selection.Paste();
            //Check if the pasted content is image and then add caption to it


        }
```

Comment: A keyboard shortcut can be used for pasting.

Comment: The above code will be invoked for shortcuts, paste option from ribbon or context menu